# Error Umbral 5000 registros Sharepoint Online 2013

Tags: angularjs, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Tengo una aplicacion desarrollada en AngularJS(Angular 1) y utilizo Sharepoint Online 2013 para guardar y consultar datos.

Tengo el siguiente bloque de código.

```
    vm.liberadosGridOptions = {

                dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({

                    pageSize: 10,
                    serverFiltering: true,
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "../_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Lista')/items?$select=*,Cliente/Id&$expand=Cliente",

                            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                                xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', "application/json;odata=verbose");
                            },
                            data: function () {

                                return {
                                    $filter: "(Estado1 eq '1' or Estado2 eq 'Liberado 0') and Cliente/Id eq '" + vm.Cliente.Id + "'",
                                    $top: "5000"

                                };
                            }
                        },
                        dataType: "JSON",
```

Ya le puse el top de 5000 pero igual lo ignora y genera este error

```
{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "-2147024860, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQueryThrottledException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "es-ES",
            "value": "Se intentó una operación que está prohibida porque supera el umbral de vista de lista aplicado por el administrador."
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cual es el punto, este error sucede porque evidentemente tu lista supero el limite permetido en las vistas (5000) entonces despueés de esto ya no es posible ejecutar consultas a dicha lista, lo que debes hacer es crear uno o varios índices para que puedas continuar ejecutando servicios/consultas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes mandar en la url los filtros que necesitas, algo así.

```
            dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({

                pageSize: 10,
                serverFiltering: true,
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "../_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Lista')/items?$select=*,Cliente/Id&$expand=Cliente&$filter=(Estado1 eq '1' or Estado2 eq 'Liberado 0') and Cliente/Id eq '" + vm.Cliente.Id + "'",

                        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                            xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', "application/json;odata=verbose");
                        },
                        data: function () {

                           //
                        }
                    },
                    dataType: "JSON",
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema se sigue dando porque en realidad el filtro de top se realiza luego de obtener los elementos de la base de datos. El problema de 5000 elementos es justamente no poder manejar más de 5000 elementos mediante la misma operación en una misma tabla en la bd.

Por lo tanto, intentá realizar el filtro por Ids. En mi caso, siempre tomo el primer Id y el último con dos pedidos previos utilizando el siguiente filtro:
`?$top=1&$orderby=Id` y `?$top=1&$orderby=Id desc` respectivamente.

Luego, divido la diferencia por un número menor a 5000, y realizo tantos pedidos independientes según el resultado de tal cociente filtrando por el rango de Ids.

Saludos

Comment: Hola y bienvenido! tu pregunta fue reportada como de baja calidad, así que le hice unas ediciones para que se viera mejor. Por favor revisa [tour] y [answer]. Muchas gracias por la respuesta!